# mirror image Git repository discovered in the binary side of an Eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I am returning to an Eclipse and Java project from two years ago. I thought I would give SmartGit a try. I've allowed SmartGit to find my git repositories that were formerly managed on the command line. To my surprise it found 8 repositories when I expected only 4. For example, in

.../`bin`/com/domain/utilities

SmartGit found a repository and tells me that **all the .java files are missing and all the .class files are untracked**. This seems strange. I do not remember creating a Git repository on the binary side.

What makes more sense is in

../`src`/com/domain/utilities

The files that are listed as "modified" correspond to what I recall I was editing recently. The source side seems to be as expected.

Going back to the command line and looking at the commit history from `git log` I can see that the binary log is identical to the source log, right down to the very second. Of course it is sort of not humanly possible to commit in the binaries and commit in the source simultaneously.

I previously tried to use **EGit** in October 2012 but abandoned that attempt. Was EGit likely responsible for creating this strange repository in the binary side (but with all the .java files missing and .class files untracked?)

If this mirror image commit log is not a normal output of Git, I will delete the whole .git folder on the binary side. I want to post here to see if it can be confirmed that there is no reason for Git to have created this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple. git knows that a folder is the root of a git project because it contains a `.git` directory.

Your `src` directory is apparently such a root git directory.

And your build procedure (or just Eclipse), copies every non-Java file recursively to `bin`. That includes the `.git` directory.

So, when you are inside bin, git correctly thinks that it is the root of a git project (since it has a .git directory); it correctly says that all the Java files are missing (since they have been replaced by `.class` files by the compiler), and it correctly says that all the `.class` files are untracked (since you don't have any ignore rule for such files).

You thus have two problems:

1. What should have been the root git folder from the start is the parent directory of `src`: it contains the sources, but also, I presume, your build files, scripts, documentation, etc. that **should** also be versioned into git.
2. Since `src` is the root and contains the `.git` directory, the build should ignore that `.git` directory instead of copying it to `bin`.

Comment: I think I'll just tell Eclipse to stop copying the .git directory. To move the .git directory via `mv .git ../../../..` and then `git add src/com/domain/package` seems to result in files deleted and files added. It's not smart enough to know that the .git folder was moved. Given that, a `git checkout` of something old will probably end up populating the wrong place. However, the main reason I think for keeping .git down at the package level is so package re-users can benefit from the history. (A package re-user probably wants package history, not my irrelevant project history.)

Comment: You shouldn't move the .git directory. You should move files in your git project. Just create an src directory (yes, under your current src), and move the root package to thus subdirectory. Then rename the top src directory (containing the .git) to "myProject".